# How to get Hashtable values and show in listview in another screen using J2me MIDlet

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am developing a Application in J2Me for Nokia Device.

I have created menu list and added `ClickEvents(CommandEvent)`, my problem is how to get hashtable data one by One in Display like listview in another screen by clickEvent.

Comment: I Created a list of three items and then added Evnets to them. when Event is Pressed(CommandEvent)i want to get the hashTable values and Display theme in OtherForm.

Comment: The code you posted seems to concat all phones in a String and show it on screen. Is it working?

Comment: No its not working, When i click the CallHistroy menu item its not Working. I want to Show Details in callHistoryForm in list view how..?

Comment: I have tested with textbox but i want to display in list view like phone call History in callhistoryForm

Answer (score 1):

You can make an static `Hashtable` in the Midlet class for example, and access to that `Hashtable` from other pages of your app.